# what is an alternative to password_hash() for (PHP 5 < 5.5.0)?

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, php-password-hash

According to manual: [password_hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) this function can be used for `(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)`

After searching for an alternative way I found this simple function from here: http://www.sitepoint.com/password-hashing-in-php/

```
function generateHash($password) {
    if (defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH) {
        $salt = '$2y$11$' . substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 22);
        return crypt($password, $salt);
    }
}
```

I can manage my code by using `function_exists` before using, but My question is about above alternative code if its secure or not, or is there any alternative in older versions of PHP?

Comment: `crypt()` will generate a password hash... you aren't required to generate a salt, but that's all the extra stuff you have in that function

Comment: Also see Openwall's [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For PHP versions < 5.3.7, I'd recommend:

http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

For PHP versions >= 5.3.7, use:

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Generating your own salts takes a lot of know how, because a good, proper salt requires a lot of entropy. Generating this salt in PHP is troublesome, which is why you usually end up depending on other resources to provide this string for you, such as `/dev/urandom` or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. Believe me, this isn't something you want to try yourself without serious research and consideration.

Using the new `password_*` API is recommended, but it can be problematic if you need to support older versions of PHP, which is where PHPass comes in. Gotta hate those $1 per month hosting plans with PHP 5.2

Comment: Thank you, I tried password_compact but it also has a required condition which wasn't found on the hosting server with PHP 5.4 so phppass worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

For versions of PHP > 5.3.7 but prior to 5.5.0, you can find an implementation of password_hash at https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat written by the same person that developed the version now implemented in PHP 5.5.0+ and deliberately intended to provide backward compatibility

Comment: +1 for additional information on https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat because your answer is some how duplicate :)