# basic error with password encryption in php

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I want to reset user password using php. i got user's current and new password from html form . here's php script to reset password. But it always executes `else` part even if user enters correct password. how?any solution? i know there might be a simple error but i'm new at this and couldnt find any error.

```
 $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $current_pass = $_POST['org_pass'];
    $new_pass = $_POST['new_pass'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
            $act_pass = $db_con->prepare("SELECT password FROM user WHERE u_id= ?");
            $act_pass->bindParam(1,$uid);

            $act_pass->execute();

            $actual_pass = $act_pass->fetchColumn();

            define('SALT', 'flyingrabbit');

            $typed_pass = md5(SALT.$actual_pass);

            if ($typed_pass == $current_pass)
            {
                $new_pass1 = md5(SALT . $new_pass);

                $res = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE user SET password= ? WHERE u_id=?");
                $res->bindParam(1,$new_pass1);
                $res->bindParam(2,$uid);

                $res->execute();

                 header("Location: profile.php"); 
                 exit;
            }
            else
            {


                   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert(\"You entered wrong password.\");window.location.href = 'profile.php';</script>";

             }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to replace $current_pass with $actual_pass?

Comment: i want to replace `$actual_pass` with `$new_pass`.         `$current_pass`  ..user enters in html form which is his password.  `$actual_pass` is users password stored in db.

Comment: You specified: if ($typed_pass == $current_pass)

Are you 100% positive that this is what you want? It seems to me like you should be doing:

if ($typed_pass == $actual_pass)

For typed_pass, you're turning the password in the database into the hash. You should be doing this to the input, not what's in the database.

Comment: Also, consider using a different encryption method, as MD5 is no longer secure: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: There are so many things wrong here. First you just assume you're getting a row back. Your salt is a constant, which is insecure, and you're using md5 which is also insecure. Finally success and failed logins effectively do the exact same thing: take you to profile.php without starting a session or setting any kind of var.

Comment: The real solution here is to use [the built-in password hashing functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) that will give you secure randomized salts and hashes.

Comment: @DigitalChris thanks..for help. i will take that in account.

Comment: @DigitalChris Note that the built-in functions are only available on php5.5+

Comment: @jeroen good point; in which case I would refer OP to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103340/what-is-an-alternative-to-password-hash-for-php-5-5-5-0

Comment: @DigitalChris Yep, I'm using ircmaxell's one myself one on various projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
$actual_pass = $act_pass->fetchColumn();

// ...

$typed_pass = md5(SALT.$actual_pass);

if ($typed_pass == $current_pass)
```

You are hashing the information you got from the database which - I assume - is already hashed.

You probably want:

```
$actual_pass = $act_pass->fetchColumn();

// ...

$typed_pass = md5(SALT.$current_pass);

if ($typed_pass == $actual_pass)
```

Note that [`md5` is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords?rq=1) to hash passwords.

Comment: ohh..right. thanks.  And about md5.  i searched google and read 1 or 2 books about encryption and they recommend md5. how?

Comment: @HungryDB Check the link at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare hashed **$current_pass** and **$actual_pas**s.

Replace

**$typed_pass = md5(SALT.$actual_pass);** with  **$typed_pass = md5(SALT.$current_pass);** 
**$typed_pass == $current_pass** with **$typed_pass == $actual_pass**

Answer (score 1):

It goes to the else statement because you compare `$typed_pass == $current_pass` but  on the previous line  you do this `$typed_pass = md5(SALT.$actual_pass)` you compare a hashed, salted password to a plain text password