# Store safely a password in MySQL using PHP and checking it afterwards

Tags: php, mysqli, hash, salt, crypt

I've been reading several posts and trying different techniques to store a password in MySQL. I've decided to use `crypt` and `salt` and I've been finally able to insert it on my database. The code used is the following:

```
    $cost = 10;
    $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
    $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password, $salt);
    $query = "INSERT INTO users_registered(name , password) VALUES('$name', '$hash')"; 
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

The main problem that I've been struggling for hours is how to check if the password I put is the correct... I am sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm completely new in this field of security, and all the posts I checked haven't worked for me. This is the code I use to check:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_POST['name'] );
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con,$_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users_registered where name='$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hash=$row['password'];
if ($hash->hash==crypt($password, $hash->hash)) {
    echo "YEEEESSS";    
        }
else {
   echo "What I'm doing wrooooong!";}
```

The problem comes from the `if`, but I'm not sure what I should put :S
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `password_hash()` would be better if you're running PHP 5.5+ : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: And for php<5.5 there is a link to a userland fill-in in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I'm using php<5.5, and gives me the error of undefined function when using `password_hash()`... @VolkerK I'll check right away!

Comment: @Alvaro look up https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat if you have PHP 5.3.7 . otherwise read up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103340/what-is-an-alternative-to-password-hash-for-php-5-5-5-0

Comment: See also for below php version 5.3 : http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: BTW, you should not use php version < 5.3. It doesn't make any sense for now.

Comment: what is the password column's type and most importantly its length? and is your HTML form correct with name attributes to match your POST arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments is already suggested, the best way is to use `password_hash()` instead of using:

```
$cost = 10;
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
$hash = crypt($password, $salt);
```

In my case, my php version was under 5.5, and I haven't been able to insert the library [compatible with lower versions](http://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat), even if it is the safest way!!

In order to check if my password stored was the same as the one the user inputs via `$_POST`, the if has to be modified as follows:

```
if (crypt($password, $hash) == $hash) {
   ...
```

and this did the trick!! Take into account that I'm just a begginer, and this method can be unsafe :)

Comment: Why couldn't you use the compatibility pack, just include this [php file](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php). Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: Ah! I thought I had to install the hole library, and I'm doing all the tests with a GoDaddy server, which limits all my instalations... The PHP they use by default is 5.4. I can switch to php 5.5, but the command was neither recognised :S. Even though, I'll try by just using the php file! Thanks :)